# QGIS Slow Rendering of ArcGIS Feature Server Layer

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, arcgis-portal, feature-service

I am trying to use the following layer in QGIS:
https://services1.arcgis.com/JZM7qJpmv7vJ0Hzx/arcgis/rest/services/DRAFT_WWNP_Riparian_Woodland_Potential/FeatureServer/0

I have added it as an ArcGIS Feature Server Layer but it doesn't draw/draws slowly compared to in ArcMap/ArcGIS Pro.

Are Feature Server Layers like this not a good idea to use in QGIS?

Answer (score 1):

My experience with a similar situation lead me to conclude that WFS by Arc does not conform fully to standards. The experience is quite variable. Some layers work fine.
My answer is for you to contact the data custodian and ask them to republish the WFS, hopefully with a different iteration of the Arc server software.